# What's difference between cURL and my Go requests?

Tags: http, go, curl, cookies

I'm tryin to repeat a few http requests, that were performed using cURL, with Go.

In first request I'm getting cookie named "yandexuid":

```
$ curl --cookie-jar jar --output /dev/null \
https://oauth.yandex.ru/...&client_id=ID
```

Then I do POST with authentication data:

```
$ curl -v --cookie jar --cookie-jar jar \
    --data 'login=LOGIN' \
    --data 'passwd=PASS' \
    --data 'twoweeks=no' \
    --data 'retpath=https://oauth.yandex.ru/...type=token' \
    https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?...&mode=qr
```

It returns many new cookies that will be used on the next step.

When I trying to do it with Go, first part works fine: cookie "yandexuid" comes and I attach it to next request. But second request don't returns cookies. Server respond's me with redirect page where it says: "*Request processing error. An error has occurred. To log in to Yandex correctly, you need to enable cookies in your browser settings.*"

My Go code:

```
type Client struct {
    HTTPClient      *http.Client
    CookieJar       []http.Cookie
}

func (c* Client) AddCookies(cookies []*http.Cookie) {
    for _, f := range cookies {
        c.CookieJar = append(c.CookieJar, *f)
    }
}

func (c *Client) Request(method string, request string, body io.Reader) *http.Response {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, request, body)

    for _, f := range c.CookieJar {
         req.AddCookie(&f) //attach cookies saving in Client structure
    }

    req.Header.Set("X-Org-id", CompanyID)
    req.Header.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

    resp, err := c.HTTPClient.Do(req)
    return resp
}

func main() {
    // first request
    _url := fmt.Sprintf(https://oauth.yandex.ru/...&client_id=%s, ClientID)
    resp := c.Request("GET", _url, nil)
    c.AddCookies(resp.Cookies()) // getting cookies from respond and saving it in Client structure

    // second request
    PostData := strings.NewReader("login="+email+"&passwd="+pass+"&twoweeks=no&retpath=https://oauth.yandex.ru/...type=token")
resp = c.Request("POST", "https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?...&mode=qr", PostData) 
}
```

What's difference between cURL and my Go requests? I know I do something wrong with cookies and as a result server think user's browser not saving cookies.

Comment: I recommend checking that the first request actually succeeds and returns cookies. You should also consider using the net/http/cookiejar package:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/

Comment: @Imars I checked, it does that. But I removed it from the code so as not to overload the question.

Comment: Ok, I suggest using net/http/cookiejar to reduce the chance that your code is doing the wrong thing. Here is an example: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/#example_New

Comment: @Imars cookiejar example works fine for me, thanks!

Comment: Aside: you are not encoding the form values. Use [url.Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) to build the request body correctly.